# Capture Solidity Emit Events without Web3 -- E.g., Calling via Postman

Tags: solidity, events

Is there some way to capture Solidity Emit Events without the use of Web3? For example, I am calling via Postman JSON RPC eth_sendTransaction. How to capture the returned results?

Answer (score 0):

Web3 is simply a convenience tool.

You cannot capture emitted events from a simple sendTransaction, since events are only emitted once the transaction is mined. You do, however, get the transaction hash back.

You can use this to later get a transaction receipt for a given transaction, which will contain the logged events (if any).

If you wish to continuously monitor for some known events, you can also set a [filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newfilter) and poll that.